# C Pointer to negative length array strange behaviour Apple LLVM compiler

Tags: c, llvm, armv7, ipad-2, ios6.1

I know that negative length arrays have undefined behaviours, but with the standard of E1[E2] being identical to (*((E1)+(E2))) I expected something to work.

So in this instance what I do is I create an array that spans in direction -32, so the accessible indexes I expected to gain are -31 up to 0.

I am using 8bit unsigned chars of 0 to 255 and signed chars of -128 to +127, but this happens with 32bit integers and 64bit integers too.

I use C99's ability to declare arrays of variable length to construct the negative spanning array, specifically I am compiling to the GNU99 C standards.

I assign these values to the indexes and print them out as I go, all seems to work fine.

It goes strange when I make a pointer to the value at array index [-31] and then loop through that, 0 to 31, printing the values.

```
const signed char length = 32;
const signed char negativeLength = -length;

signed char array[negativeLength];
for ( signed char ii = 0; ii > negativeLength; ii-- ) {
    array[ii] = ii;
    printf( "array %d\n", array[ii] ); /* Prints out expected values */
}

printf( "==========\n" );

signed char * const pointer = &array[negativeLength + 1];
for ( unsigned char ii = 0; ii < length; ii++ ) {
    printf( "pointer %d\n", pointer[ii] ); /* Begins printing expected values then goes funky */
}
```

I get different results every time, but with 32 it generally starts out okay for the first 3 values, it then goes funky and starts printing out -93 up to +47 and then at index pointer[8], array[-23] it goes fine again.

I am running this on an iPad 2.

What exactly is going on here? Is the iPad messing with the pointer or the array when it detects the negative spanning array length?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior and clobbering memory that does not belong to you. There's nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes advocate understanding the behavior observed in some C implementations in situations where the C standard does not define the behavior, because it can be illuminating about how certain implementing work or how computers work. In this case, however: Do not do that.

To access an array with arbitrary integer indices, from X (inclusive) to Y (exclusive), do this:

```
ElementType ArrayMemory[Y-X], *Array = ArrayMemory - X;
```

If X <= 0 <= Y and X < Y, the behavior of this is defined by the C standard.

Comment: That's a really cool way of going around this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect something to work when you've done something with undefined behaviour?

While `E1[E2]` being equivalent to `*(E1 + E2)` is well defined, the data you're accessing is not well defined so all bets are off.

Comment: I didn't expect it to work, I was shocked to see that the initial reading did work, however it's also then strange for looping through the pointer to then produce different results, the question is what is going on that causes this

Comment: the thing about undefined behaviour is that it can work as you (mistakenly) expect it to work. You can't rely on anything. Do not seek to understand why it works. Seek to understand what undefined behaviour means instead.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming undefined behaviour means that the C standards do not cover such cases and as such either the compiler can implement such cases or they can be ignored which ends up with crazy, unexpected results as above?

Comment: the behaviour is undefined. The resulting program can behave as expected, or reformat your hard disk, or crash, and it doesn't have to do the same thing between different executions of the code invoking undefined behaviour. The behaviour are UNDEFINED. This means it is NOT DEFINED. It is NOT DEFINED if it will do the same thing or a different thing next time. It is NOT DEFINED what thing it will do this time.

Do not try to work out what it will do or why it does it. Just work out how not to invoke it.